# JS Need help to add href on img

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, appendchild, setattribute

i'm using Innova Content Builder to record my webpage.
It's contains a module called saveimage.php which transforms binary images to jpg files.
This works perfectly.

Now, i would like to encapsulate these img whith href links, but it doesn't works.

Here is my code :

```
parent.document.getElementById('img-" . $count . "').setAttribute('src','" . $urlpath . $image . "');
parent.document.getElementById('img-" . $count . "').setAttribute('alt','".$image."');
var myLink = document.createElement('a');
myLink.setAttribute('href','http://www.google.fr');
parent.document.getElementById('img-" . $count . "').appendChild(myLink);
```

This code is placed into a body onload function.
I think it's a parentality problem.

Can you help me ? Thanks !

Comment: It seems you didn't insert myLink into parent item.

Comment: What is the issue? "_it doesn't works_" doesn't tell anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<script>
    parent.document.getElementById('img-" . $count . "').setAttribute('src','" . $urlpath . $image . "');
    parent.document.getElementById('img-" . $count . "').setAttribute('alt','".$image."');
var myLink = document.createElement('a');
myLink.setAttribute('href','http://www.google.fr');
    parent.document.getElementById('img-" . $count . "').parentNode.insertBefore(myLink, parent.document.getElementById('img-" . $count . "'));
    myLink.appendChild(parent.document.getElementById('img-" . $count . "'));
</script>
```

Comment: Very Nice, thank you very much.
Additionnally question please : when i upload a new image on the first one, the system maintains the first href link. How can i delete all href links before create new ?

For example :
<a href="../images/btennis-qooy9k.jpg"></a><a href="../images/bmouett-pa6pyy.jpg"><img src="../images/bmouett-pa6pyy.jpg" id="img-1"></a>